# Determine whether a video was clicked

Tags: javascript, html, ads

I'm trying to register/log ad clicks on my site. 
I run video ads and want to know if it is possible to some how register an ad click.

One idea that I'm thinking about is to place a div over the video then onclick do some function foo.

Can you please point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Is the video played with an embedded flash object? If so, you will have to be able to modify the flash video player.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Google Anlytics, you can add this to each div you want to track.  In GA it will organize the clicks in by what page the user was on for the click and which video was clicked.

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Video', window.location.pathname , href]);"
```

Comment: very very nice. had no idea you could push custom tags to analytics

Comment: Now that UA is out in Google Analytics this changed to:  onClick= "ga('send', 'event', 'video', window.location.pathname, href);"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for exactly. I would recommend wrapping a div around whatever you're trying to count.

```
var clicks = 0;
$('#someDiv').click(function(){
    clicks++;
});
```

This will count how many times a user clicks on that div. Or if you just want to see if a user clicked on a div:

```
$('#someDiv').click(function(){
    alert('you clicked on a div');
});
```

Comment: I like your idea. I've just done something like what you suggested... check it out http://www.main.waveshare.tv/

Comment: The only problem with this now is that you can't watch the video